# Proving that $B_1$ and $B_2$ doesn't have maximal element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory

This is one of the problem I have been solving form Velleman's How to prove book:

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$, $B_1 \subseteq A$, $B_2
>  \subseteq A$, $\forall x \in B_1 \exists y \in B_2 (xRy)$, and $\forall
>  x \in B_2 \exists y \in B_1(xRy)$.
>
> Prove that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint then neither of them has a
>   maximal element.

Now I have tried to prove it by contradiction by assuming that $B_1$
has maximal element. But that is not leading me to anywhere. Any
thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We let $\leq$ be our order.

Suppose $B_1$ has a maximal element $x$.

Then by the hypothesis there is an element $y$ in $B_2$ so that $x\leq y$.

by our hypothesis there is an element $z$ in $B_1$ so that $y\leq z$

By transitivity $x\leq z$.

If $x=z$ then $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ but we know $x\neq y$ because $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint, this is a contradiction.

Therefore we must have $x<z$ which is also a contradiction because $x$ is maximal. The contradiction comes from assuming $B_1$ has a maximal element, we conclude $B_1$ has no maximal element.

(Proving $B_2$ has no maximal element is analogous).

Comment: By which hypothesis are you concluding $y \leq z$ ?

Comment: I can see that $y \in B_2$ and $z \in B_2$. But how does it follows that $y \leq z$ ?

Comment: I re-wrote a lot of the solution, is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks. But how do you suppose that $x = z$. What if $x \neq z$ ?

Comment: case $1$ is $x=z$ which is impossible. Case $2$ is when $x>z$ which yields the desired contradiction.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Finally got it.